# Databricks Error in SQL statement: SecurityException: User does not have permission SELECT on table

Tags: azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am still getting familiar with the new Databricks Notebook.

When I enter the SQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mydatabase.mytable 

AS 

SELECT 
  pers.first_name as first_name,
  pers.last_name as last_name,
  r.role_code as role_code,
 FROM 
  product_master
  INNER JOIN global.date_dim dd on dd.date_key = ptplf.date_key
```

(I have omitted a lot of the code for brevity)

I get the error:

```
Error in SQL statement: SecurityException: User cannot SELECT on table `mydatabase`.`mytable` because:
--The owner of table `global`.`date_dim` is different from the owner of table `mydatabase`.`mytable`.
```

It would appear the issue is on security

Comment: GRANT SELECT ON global.date_dim TO myuser;
GRANT SELECT ON mydatabase.mytable TO myuser;

Comment: can you try this

Comment: Hi @DileeprajnarayanThumula, thanks for reaching out. I tried your suggestion, but I got the following error ```Error in SQL statement: SecurityException: User does not own table `global`.`date_dim`.```

Comment: I also tried a simple way to test by executing the code ```refresh table mydatabase.mytable``` and I got the error ```Error in SQL statement: SecurityException: User cannot SELECT on table `mydatabase`.`mytable` because:
--The owner of table `global`.`date_dim` is different from the owner of table `mydatabase`.`mytable`.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Make sure you have permission to read data from mydatabase.mytable. Otherwise, get permission from admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have permission to read data from mydatabase.mytable. If not, obtain permission from the admin to read data from mydatabase.mytable by following the procedure below:

In the SQL editor, select the database, right-click on the database, and choose `open in catalog explorer` as shown below:

[image]

This will open the Catalog window. Select the table, navigate to permissions, click on 'grant', select the user, and click on the `SELECT` permission before clicking 'grant' as shown below:

[image]

This will grant the user access to read data from the table.